# Viable locator strategies for partial link text in webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, appium

I'm testing a messaging app, and I'm planning to have the code wait until it receives the message, "Hello, my name is Jeff."

2 pieces of failed code I tried:

```
msg_receive_1 = WebDriverWait(driver1, 15).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Hello"))
    )
```

```
msg_receive_1 = WebDriverWait(driver1, 15).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Hello, my name is Jeff."))
    )
```

Is visibility of element located a sub-par choice for partial link text? If so, what would be a viable alternative?

If the issue is something else, what could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question

> Is visibility of element located a sub-par choice for partial link
> text?

No, absolutely no.

See what is underneath of `visibility_of_element_located` Method :-

> ```
> """ An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a
> page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed
> but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.
> locator - used to find the element
> returns the WebElement once it is located and visible
> """
> ```

```
class visibility_of_element_located(object):
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False
```

so basically it calls,

```
_element_if_visible
```

and this is what we have

```
def _element_if_visible(element, visibility=True):
    return element if element.is_displayed() == visibility else False
```

So, direct answer to your question is No. But it depends, how you have defined EC, in your case, Are you sure if that is the unique `link_text` or `partial_link_text`,
did you try changing that to css or xpath and verified like below ?

```
//*[contains(text(),'Hello')]
```

in code :

```
msg_receive_1 = WebDriverWait(driver1, 15).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Hello')]"))
    )
```

as an xpath ?

Comment: I believe my XPATH changes with every run so I'm avoiding it. Are there any other options that would also be viable?

Comment: yes, Can you share HTML ? there are 8 known locators, we can give it a try with others as well

Comment: I don't think my app has HTML values (if it does, Appium's not giving me that).

I have elementId, index, package, class, text, and resource-id.

Comment: How do you differentiate between tags ? even for mobile apps, you need to identify element uniquely

Answer (score 1):

You should use XPath, not Link Text.
Try this:

```py
msg_receive_1 = WebDriverWait(driver1, 15).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Hello')]"))
)
```

or this:

```py
msg_receive_1 = WebDriverWait(driver1, 15).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Hello, my name is Jeff')]"))
)
```

If you are sure about the text string, it can be this too:

```py
msg_receive_1 = WebDriverWait(driver1, 15).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Hello, my name is Jeff.']"))
)
```

Comment: I believe my XPATH changes with every run so I'm avoiding it. Are there any other options that would also be viable?

Comment: Please share a link to that page or at least the HTML code of that page, I hope we will be able to locate that element uniquely

Comment: It's an app so I don't have HTML. I have elementId, index, package, class, text, and resource-id, which of these would be helpful?

Comment: It should be some unique attribute. Or unique sequence of attributes/values. Now I understand, this is a mobile app, but I can't know what attribute value or sequence will be unique.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a unique attribute for my constant elements, is there any viable workaround or no?

Comment: I can't answer this question without seeing the elements with Spy etc.

Comment: There is no reason you would NOT use Xpath with contains, as your path changes and you have no unique attributes, this answer will be the only stable one that you can rely.
What is the problem of the xpath changing if you are using the contains of xpath to find the element? No matter what happens in the DOM, if you are looking for a specific TEXT with contains and it has the text, you will find it.